# LibGDX example game Thrust Copter lags

Tags: java, libgdx

I have read **LibGDX Game Development Essentials** book and there you can find Thrust Copter game example. Problem is if you run this game you will see little lags when you look at the stars or obstacles, just look carefully. Can somebody explain me why is this happening? Because I am making a game and I have a similar problem with this issue, when I drawing and moving objects I can see lags. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell without the source code.. and I don't plan on buying the book to figure it out. Is the source code exactly the same as [this github project?](https://github.com/vladthelittleone/thrust-copter)

Comment: I probably found out why this was happening. The problem is described and solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532438/libgdx-game-lags-when-rendering?noredirect=1#comment54846668_33532438). Removing objects from the Array which is iterated through causes mini lags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably found out why this is happening. The problem is described and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532438/libgdx-game-lags-when-rendering?noredirect=1#comment54846668_33532438). Removing objects from the Array which is iterated through causes mini lags.